# Unable to launch DynamoDB after installation on AWS-ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I Have launched EC2 instance and followed thw installation procedure of dynamoDB as shown in the below link

```
https://garywoodfine.com/how-to-install-dynamodb-on-local-ubuntu-development/
```

I was able to successfully install DynamoDB as shown below:

```
Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:       false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:       false
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams:     *
```

but when i try to launch with DynamoDb using a browser with the link as shown in the document

```
http://localhost:8000/shell/
```

it's not launching

I have done the following:

1. I have changed the localhost to vm's public IP as shown below

   http://x.xxx.xx.xx:8000/shell/
2. inbound and outbound rule are set correctly to allow all traffic, http, https

still not nothing is working.

I want to open dynamoDB UI on the browser

Kindly suggest what to do.

Comment: Why are you installing DynamoDB local on EC2?

Comment: Because I am trying install DynamoDB  on AWS EC-2 Instance as it is one of the new requirement

Comment: You don't install it. You just use DynamoDB on the cloud not from your EC2 instance. DynamoDB local is meant for local testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamoDB Local Web Shell was deprecated with version 1.16.X and is not available any longer from 1.17.X to latest. Refer [Dynamodb local web shell does not load](https://repost.aws/questions/QUHyIzoEDqQ3iOKlUEp1LPWQ#ANdBm9Nz9TRf6VqR3jZtcA1g) for more detail.

The latest solution that AWS offers for the same is **NoSQL Workbench for DynamoDB**.

More details here - [NoSQL Workbench for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html)